# Trouble decoding json into php output

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to decode json and display results with php but getting nothing back. Could anyone take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is an example of my php :

```
class League

{
public function __construct($region, $id, $summid)  {
    global $apiKey;
    global $errorAPI;
    $data = RIOT_API . "$region/v2.3/league/by-summoner/" . urlencode($summid) . "?api_key=$apiKey";
    $info = httpResp($data);
    if ($info[1] == false)
        {
        $League = json_decode(file_get_contents($data) , true);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($League['entries']); $i++)
            {
            if ($League['entries'][$i]['playerOrTeamId'] == $summid)
                {
                $floor = $i;
                break;
                }
            }

        $this->leaguename = $League['entries'][$floor]['leagueName'];
        $this->tier = $League['entries'][$floor]['tier'];
        $this->points = $League['entries'][$floor]['leaguePoints'];
        $this->rank = $League['entries'][$floor]['rank'];
        $this->wins = $League['entries'][$floor]['wins'];
        $this->exists = true;
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Error " . $info[0] . " - " . array_search($info[0], $errorAPI);
        $this->exists = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my php for outputting:

```
$newLeague1 = new League("euw", "Deew0n", "24361317");

echo '<br />League Name : ', $newLeague1->name;
echo "\n";
echo '<br />Position : ', $newLeague1->position;
echo "\n";
echo '<br />League Points : ', $newLeague1->leaguePoints;
echo "\n";
echo '<br />Wins/Losses: ', $newLeague1->wins, "/", $newLeague1->totalgames;
echo "\n";
echo '<br />Division Name: ', $newLeague1->tier, ' ', $newLeague1->rank;
```

And lastly this is the json I am dealing with : http://pastebin.com/9FKgrjeS

Comment: @Newbi3 Not in an `echo` statement they don't

Comment: Also do a `var_dump($League);` of $League and lets see what you get in that object. We'll know if it is properly parsed or not

Comment: What is `httpResp()`? Also, using globals is a terrible way to code. Instead, pass in the dependencies to your class where required.

Comment: I also suggest you enable proper error reporting as you're undoubtedly hitting some undefined index errors. Set `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL` in your `php.ini` file and restart your web server

Comment: In addition to @Phil's comments. Do your error logs say anything? I typically use $ `tail -f /var/log/apache2/location_to_error.log` as an example, in a terminal window and keep it running

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Jayce's Emmissaries",
        "tier": "SILVER",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [ {...}, {...} ]
        "participantId": "24361317"
    }
]
```

...which is an array with 1 item: an object with 5 items.

If you can change the JSON, remove the outer [], otherwise change the code to access this [0]th entry.

Comment: Nice catch! OP could also use `$League = reset($League)`. I doubt they'd be able to change the response format as it appears to be from a remote API.

Comment: How would I change the code to access the entries?
As Phil mentioned the response is from a remote API so unable to change the format

Comment: As Phil said: `$League = reset($League);` this sets $League to the first entry of the array, so e.g. $League['name'] should than be valid